# Install Mongo 3.2.9 on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

i installed mongodb in ubuntu usinfg the following links
https://askubuntu.com/questions/724749/install-mongo-3-2-on-ubuntu-15-10

```
root@karthickeyan:/home/karthickeyan# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
connecting to: test
2016-08-20T01:17:08.198+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-08-20T01:17:08.198+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Is the MongoDB service running?

Comment: no, it's not running

Comment: Start the service using: `sudo service mongodb start` then run the command `mongo` to access it. Let me answer the question.

Comment: You need to start MongoDB daemon (`mongod`) first. What is the output of `sudo systemctl status mongod`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the file `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongodb.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Start the service:

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

Then run the command:

```
mongo
```

You will then access the server. Hope it works for you. :)

Comment: sudo service mongodb start
 mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
connecting to: test
2016-08-20T01:36:37.947+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-08-20T01:36:37.947+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed

Comment: i get above  error, while giving cmmand sudo service mongodb  start then mongo

Comment: fast two i having this issue

Comment: do i need to upgrade 16.04

Comment: No, not yet. Just follow the updated answer lets see.

Comment: Great, you know what to do with my answer :)

Comment: after i created file /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service, i gave following command  sudo service mongod start
Warning: mongod.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
then i gave that systemctl daemon-reload command then entered Mongo command it's working fine right now

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. You can validate the answer :)